# auto increment $this->input->post() variable name and input name

Tags: php, codeigniter, increment

I am creating a project of Test that composed of 100 questions. I'm using CODEIGNITER HMVC

here is the script in my view/display that generate and auto increment the name of question choice and question id to be send in controller.

```
<script>

function submit_answer(){
    $.post('<?php echo site_url('iqtest_stud_ans/submit_answer'); ?>',
         {
            <?php
            $i = 100;
            for($c=1;$c<=$i;$c++){
            ?>
            qchoice<?php echo $c; ?>    : $('input[name=qchoice<?php echo $c; ?>]:checked').val(),
            q_id<?php echo $c; ?>       : $('#q_id<?php echo $c; ?>').val(),
            <?php } ?>
            take_no                     : $('#take_no').val(),
         }
    );
}
```

in my script I don't have any problem, things are working properly. I was able to send all the data in my controller. And here's my problem comes. Because I don't want to make my life miserable so I want to use the for loop the same as how I did in my script.

here's my code in my controller.

```
$i=100;
        $q_id101 = $this->input->post('q_id1');
        for($c=1;$c<=$i;$c++){
            ${'q_id' . $c} = $this->input->post('{"qchoice" . $c}');
            ${'choice' . $c} = $this->input->post("{'qchoice' . $c}");
        }//below codes are working.
        $e=100;
        for($d=1;$d<=$e;$d++){
            $data = array(
                'q_id'      => ${'q_id' . $d},
                'answer'    => ${'choice' . $d},
                'stud_no'   => $stud_no,
                'take_no'   => $take_no
                );
            print_r($data);
            $update = $this->mdl_stud_ans->_insert($data);
        }
```

the variable works fine ${'q_id' . $c} but the increment inside post wasn't working $this->input->post('{"qchoice" . $c}');

my question is... is there a way for me to increment the name of a input/field inside the post()?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this

```
${'q_id' . $c} = $this->input->post('qchoice' . $c);
${'choice' . $c} = $this->input->post('qchoice' . $c);
```

Comment: What you get if you print `$this->input->post();`

Comment: echo/print this $this->input->post('qchoice' . $c); 
none/blank. but if $this->input->post('qchoice1'); I was able to get the value.

Comment: make sure $c has value; check like this way `$c=1;echo $this->input->post('qchoice' . $c);` basically  `$this->input->post('qchoice1');` and `$this->input->post('qchoice' . $c);` are same if `$c==1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Shaiful. Anyway, this is how I solved it.

```
$i=100;

    for($c=1;$c<=$i;$c++){
        $varq_id = 'q_id'.$c; //I add this
        $varqchoice = 'qchoice'.$c; //I add this
        ${'q_id' . $c} = $this->input->post($varq_id); //and place the variable inside the post().
        ${'choice' . $c} = $this->input->post($varqchoice);
    }
```

I hope this will help other developers.

Happy Coding!